# Iterative Greedy Algorithm Explaination

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Could anyone explain the Iterative Greedy Algorithm with example, and kindly briefly explain the Construction and Destruction process...

Comment: Which greedy algorithm? There is no such thing as *"the greedy algorithm"*, greedy is a kind of algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm

Comment: Obviously you should reformulate your question very seriously. If you have problems with understanding of some information of a book, you cannot give us that book and wait that we'll find your problem there. Put down exactly what you do not understand. You haven't improved your question for 2 days. Even the reference to the book is in the comments, not in the question.  - I am voting for closing, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Greedy** is not an algorithm, but a term, used for many different algorithms. It means that looking for a sequence of elements that fulfill some condition, we take a longer possible sequence. The antonym, **lazy**, means choosing the first found sequence.

Both terms are not **mathematically strict**, they only help to better understand what we are talking about. They have an exact sense only in some context.

Look for [**greedy** term in regex explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions), for example.

> A greedy algorithm is any algorithm that follows the problem-solving
>   heuristic of making the locally optimal choice at each stage with
>   the intent of finding a global optimum.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm)

More easily, **greedy** means taking some branch and NOT checking it for throwing it off.

Again, being greedy does not mean anything exact, it only about the classification of similar algorithms.

Comment: if not algorithm then kindly explain Iterated Greedy?? is purpose and how its use with example
http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/IridiaTrSeries/rev/IridiaTr2018-006r001.pdf

Comment: Please, notice, we are talking about very precise things. And all your words and sentences should be written most precisely. If you want to change the question, edit it, do not rephrase it in comments. Thus your question can be improved - now it is not of high quality. Also, do not use different words (iterated, iterative) for the same thing. Or is it not the same?

Comment: What do you NOT understand in the algorithm at the top of the first page of the document cited by you?

Comment: Please go through the paper mentioned below http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/IridiaTrSeries/rev/IridiaTr2018-006r001.pdf

Comment: It's using iterated greedy algorithm to solve tsp problem. I want to know how it's solving it

Comment: Obviously you should reformulate your question very seriously. If you have problems with understanding of some information of a book, you cannot give us that book and wait that we'll find your problem there. Put down exactly what you do not understand.